# How do I install an OLD version of Geth and Swarm?

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm

I need to install an old version of Swarm : version 1.7.3-stable , but I can't figure out how to install it from the command line.

I'm on Mac OSX.

I've found these old downloads: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/ but I can't figure out how to install them on my machine. I'd prefer to install from source, if possible.

I can only manage to install the latest versions of geth and swarm:

$geth version
Geth
Version: 1.8.14-stable
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.10.3
Operating System: Darwin
GOPATH=/Users/me/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.3/libexec

$swarm version
Swarm
Version: 0.3.2-stable
Go Version: go1.10.3
OS: Darwin

However, these latest versions aren't compatibile with the code of the project I've just joined.

The team I've joined are using Geth 1.7.3 and Swarm 1.7.3 (note that it appears Swarm version numbers used to coincide with Geth version numbers, but have since separated, as you can see with my versions above). I need to revert both Geth and Swarm back to 1.7.3 on my machine.

Is there a way to clone and install an old version from a github repo? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can geth the source code for the right version here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases and then compile it. There are also the binaries, they should work too (although I am not familiar with MAC OSX)

Answer (score 1):

Old releases are available in `Releases` section of Ethereum's repository. Both, source code and binary distribution: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

And btw, 1.7.3 is not so old, a lot of nodes are still running on 1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

you need download the source and check out with your version like 1.7.3 then compile it with proper go version like 1.9 , then you got it.

Answer (score 1):

An older version of Geth can be installed using tar file, here I am using version 1.8.16. To download the required Geth file, we need to check the OS version using the following command.

```
> dpkg --print-architecture   
amd64
```

Once you have your OS information, download (amd64 tar in our case) file from the Geth website.

Upload downloaded tar file on a server and extract using the following command:

```
sudo tar -xvf <filename>
```

In our case,

```
sudo tar -xvf  geth-linux-amd64-1.8.16-477eb093.tar.gz
```

Step into extracted folder

```
cd geth-linux-amd64-1.8.16-477eb093
```

It should contain the geth file, make it executable with the below command.

```
sudo chmod +x geth
```

Copy file to the user bin.

```
sudo cp geth /usr/local/bin/
```

Check the Geth version with the following command

```
> geth version  
Version: 1.8.16-stable
```

Geth is now installed successfully on the system

Ref: [How To Install Geth On A Linux Machine](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-install-geth-on-linux-machine)